# How do I make my password protected directory prompt the user to login on each visit?

Tags: caching, password-protection

I have enabled password protection on a directory via the control panel of my hosting server. It is working fine. However, the problem is that user's browsers are caching their login information, so that if they navigate away from the page and then back to the password protected page - they are not prompted to login again.

I have been reading about ways to prevent a browser from caching and have tried the META tag options (pragma, cache control, expires) but that does not fully work. It only works if the user closes out of the browser completely, then opens the browser again. I'm wanting the login prompt to open EACH time the user accesses the page (kind of like accessing a webmail page).

I'm curious if there is some sort of coding that can help with this. My page is simply using css and html - the only 2 codings I am familiar with.

Comment: Why do you every time want to ask for authentication?

Comment: The need for it to ask for authentication each time is how my boss prefers for it to be :)

Comment: Do you have the possibility to use a Php Script? This would be more secure. ..

Comment: My hosting does support Php, however I have very little experience with Php coding...I'm willing to learn and try though.

Comment: So wait I am creating an answer explaining this.

Comment: Is it ok if the authentication is done by a php script and not a htaccess?

Comment: Sure! I actually tried the .htaccess method and was not able to get that to work. Also FYI, we have unique usernames and passwords for each user to access the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating Basic with PHP:

The Login:

```
<?php session_start();$_SESSION=array();session_destroy(); ?>
<form method="POST" action="yoursite.php">
Username: <input name="username"><br>
Password: <input name="password" type="password"><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

YourSite:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $username = trim($_POST['username']);
  $userpw = trim($_POST['password']);
  //here you have to check if the credentials are correct
    $user_may_see_content = false;
  //
  if(user_may_see_content) {
   $_SESSION['mayHaveRequest']=1;
   //now go to page

  } else {
   header("Location: <link_to_loginsite>");exit();
  }

}

//if user may see page
if(isset($_SESSION['mayHaveRequest']) && $_SESSION['mayHaveRequest']==1): ?>
$_SESSION['mayHaveRequest']=0;
?>
<!-- SECRET HTML CODE FOR AUTHENTICATED USERS -->



<?php else: 
header("Location: <link_to_loginsite>");exit();
endif;
?>
```

This is just an example for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I'm experimenting with what you have provided. This is my first attempt at using php.

Comment: I was able to create the login page. I am confused about where on the password protected site the PHP needs to be placed.

Comment: At the top .. because you can set the header("Location: <redirect_url>") to redirect the user e.g. if he is not logged in. if you have outputed content you can not anymore because the header were already sent.